# Replace placeholders in a string with dynamic content

Tags: c#

I would like to use the .split function or any function that would allow me to read a text file and take values created in the application and put them into the certain areas in the text file where the split symbols are.

For Example:
example text file: template.txt
My name is *. I am * year(s) old. I was born on *.

`textbox1 = Jim`
`textbox2 = 25`
`textbox3 = 08/14/2012`

I would like the values from textbox1 thru textbox3 to be added into a new text file with the lines from the template.txt at the "*" symbols. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

You could hold the text in textfile in this format

> My name is {0}. I am {1} year(s) old. I was born on {2}

Then you load it to string and format it like `string.Format("My name is {0}. I am {1} year(s) old. I was born on {2}", textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, textbox3.Text)`

After that you have changed your string, save it to textfile again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the question is clear, what actually you want to do, split the string, or merge the text from different textboxes and put the lines in to the text file.

Comment: I would like to take the original text file with the "*" symbols and create a new text file with the info from the text boxes merged into it.